# Find out if a product has been changed

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if a customer has cancelled one product (finish_date) and started another (start_date) within one month

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `customer_number` char(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_number` char(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `finish_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO subscription (customer_number, product_number, start_date, finish_date) VALUES('1', '1', '2019-12-01', '2020-11-01');
INSERT INTO subscription (customer_number, product_number, start_date, finish_date) VALUES('1', '2', '2020-12-13', NULL);
INSERT INTO subscription (customer_number, product_number, start_date, finish_date) VALUES('2', '1', '2019-12-01', '2020-12-01');
INSERT INTO subscription (customer_number, product_number, start_date, finish_date) VALUES('2', '2', '2020-12-13', NULL);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec202c

Comment: You forgot to add the SQL statement to your fiddle.....

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried, please? And could you provide a sample of your expected results? "Within one month" meaning between start_date and finish_date there's 30 days? Or that they start and finish within the same month and year?

Comment: Note that relational tables (the kind that you typically find in relational databases) have PRIMARY KEYs

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: Sorry, my query wasn't save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct
   s1.customer_number,
   s1.product_number,
   s1.finish_date,
   s2.start_date
from subscription s1
inner join subscription s2
   on s2.customer_number=s2.customer_number
     and s2.product_number<>s1.product_number
     and year(s2.start_date)=year(s1.finish_date)
     and month(s2.start_date)=month(s1.finish_date);
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec202c/18)

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes (in the event that indexes are provided)

Comment: I  agree with the note that indexes will not be used this this, unless the index is only on `customer_number, product_number`, in which case it should be possible ,  for the inner join, to use this index, but it does not do so in MySQL.